# How to change recent project's background color?

Tags: goland

Does anyone know how to change the recent project's background color on Mac?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzEoF.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Customization of IntelliJ-based IDEs (GoLand, PhpStorm, etc.) themes (UI elements, controls, background colors in UI elements) is available by creating a custom theme as a plugin.

Refer to the documentation and examples for more information:

- https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/themes.html
- https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-sdk-docs/tree/main/code_samples/theme_basics